# flutter ios: xcode can not see my podfile

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

i am building a flutter app, and i was able to run it on ios yesterday. today i am trying the exact same code but xcode wont see my podfile which is visible in the finder.

Warnings:

/Users/adnan/foody/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig Debug.xcconfig line 1: Unable to find included file "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"

/Users/adnan/foody/ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig Release.xcconfig line 1: Unable to find included file "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"

Errors:

/Users/adnan/foody/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths

[xcode view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKA96.png)
[finder view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRDoI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing happened with me, please confirm if you added any pods recently?
If yes, try closing the project and then run pod install on terminal on the iOS project directory.

Then open the project again try to run it.

Hopefully it will solve your issue.